# Scrollview doesn't scroll in Xcode

Tags: uiscrollview

I have a scroll view with the constraints:

- equal width to Safe Area
- equal height to Safe Area
- Align Center X to Superview
- Align Center Y to Superview

It contains only a vertical Stack View with the following constraints:

- Align Center X to: SuperView
- Proportional Width to Superview (multiplier 0.9)
- Top Space to Superview: 0

Now, if I add enough items to the stack view, so that it exceeds the bottom of the Scrollview, I can't scroll it. Why is that so and how can I make it work?

here is my storyboard:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TZHl3d_HCptqx8ezcOpNJjH8RSitOln5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show the [code you have so far](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help. You should also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would add my storyboard, but it has more than 80000 characters and I'm only allowed 30000

Comment: ok, i uploaded it to google drive now and edited my question

Comment: can't anyone help me?